# Send to DB function not executing

Tags: php, mysql

This function gets the date from the user:

```php
function getCCGraduationDate () {
        ?>
        <form method="post" action="processor.php">
        Graduation Date: <input type="text" name="CCgraduationdate"><br>
        <input type="submit">
        <?php
    }
```

This function sends the value to a DB and is called on the processor.php page:

```php
function sendCCGraduationDate () {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","XXXXXX");
    if (!$con)
        {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("user", $con);
        $grad = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CCGraduationDate'], $con);
        $sql = "UPDATE profile SET CommunityCollegeGraduationDate='$grad' WHERE userid=$this->user_id";
        mysql_query( $sql , $con );

        mysql_close($con);

    }
```

For some reason the value isn't populating in the database. I had tested similar functions last night and they worked, not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: check if there is any errors by: `echo mysql_error($con);` right after `mysql_query( $sql , $con );`. if there is, you should see some error text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this:

FORM CODE:

```
<input type="text" name="CCgraduationdate"><br>
```

PHP CODE:

```
$grad = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['CCGraduationDate'], $con);
```

Your `CCgraduationdate` in your form is unequal to `CCGraduationDate` in your php code

If you're not getting an error like:

```
Notice:  Undefined index: CCGraduationDate /* blah blah blah */
```

Then you can try adding at the top of your PHP code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And then see if an error comes out.

Of course, that's after changing your `$sql` variable's data to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE profile SET CommunityCollegeGraduationDate='$grad' WHERE userid=" . $this->user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is an actual value for `$this->user_id`:

```
$sql = "UPDATE profile SET CommunityCollegeGraduationDate='$grad' WHERE userid=$this->user_id";

// Should be:

$sql = "UPDATE profile SET CommunityCollegeGraduationDate='$grad' WHERE userid={$this->user_id}";

// Or

$sql = "UPDATE profile SET CommunityCollegeGraduationDate='$grad' WHERE userid= " . $this->user_id;
```

-- Edit --

```
$sql = "UPDATE profile SET CommunityCollegeGraduationDate='$grad' WHERE userid= " . $this->user_id;

if (!mysql_query( $sql , $con ))
    die(mysql_error()); 
}
```

-- Edit --

```
// To avoid case and extra space issues, sanitize your var first
$grad = trim(strtolower($grad));

// You did well to escape
$grad = mysql_real_escape_string($grad, $con);
```

Comment: Can you `var_dump($this->user_id)`? Is there a value?

Comment: It's in the database and I can call it on the view page as well, not using $this->. So I tried switching this to the object name $profile-> and it still didn't work.

Comment: @mattrmclaren: Updated solution, see if it gives you a mysql error.

Comment: What type of field is userid in the database? You may want to try `WHERE userid='$this->user_id'`.

Comment: So no sql error, odd. What is the value of `var_dump($grad)`?

Comment: Is everyone ready for the big secret? My post value in the send function and get functions weren't case consistent. Someone else edited my post I think so no one noticed.

Comment: @mattrmclaren: Updated post with example variable scrubbing.